# Jquery Slider won't stop at the end

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I have a jQuery slider that slides horizontally when the next button is clicked. However, when it reaches the end of the image/list sequence, it continues to slide and doesn't stop. I managed to make it not slide off the left end, but the right end is a problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inner").css("overflow-x", "hidden"); 
    
    var xPos = $('#scroller li:last').position();
    var pos = '-' + xPos.left + 'px';
    alert(pos); 
    
    $('#next').click(function() {
        if(("#scroller ").css("margin-left") > pos ) {
            $('#scroller').animate({
                marginLeft: "-=133px"
            }, 200)
        }
    });
    
    $('#prev').click(function() {
        if($("#scroller").css("margin-left") < "0") {
            $('#scroller').animate({
                marginLeft: "+=133px"
            }, 200)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Nothing is telling it to stop. Your next button just adds a 133 margin each time. You need to somehow set a maximum margin, or even better, make your right/left button disappear after a certain margin is reached. I'll research a way and post an answer later if I have time. But that's what you should shoot for.

Comment: I tried to tell it to not move unless the margin-left value is greater than the position of the last element inside the slider.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you have a bug in the line:

```
if(("#scroller ").css("margin-left") > pos ){
```

change it to

```
if($("#scroller ").css("margin-left") > pos ){
```

if it doesnt help, maybe you should try this:

```
if(parseInt($("#scroller").css("margin-left"),0) < 0){
```

change it in the $('#prev').click function, and

```
 if(parseInt($("#scroller ").css("margin-left"),10) > parseInt(pos,10) ){
```

in the $('#next').click function